# First time parsing XML in Python: this can't be like like it was meant to be, can it?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to read data from an XML file and am using ElementTree. Reading a number of nodes looks like this ATM:

```
  def read_edl_ev_ids(xml_tree):
      # Read all EDL events (those which start with "EDL_EV_") from XML 
      # and put them into a dict with 
      # symbolic name as key and number as value. The XML looks like:
      # <...>
      # <COMPU-METHOD>
      #    <SHORT-NAME>DT_EDL_EventType</SHORT-NAME>
      #    <...> 
      #    <COMPU-SCALE>
      #       <LOWER_LIMIT>number</LOWER-LIMIT>
      #       <....>
      #       <COMPU-CONST>
      #          <VT>EDL_EV_symbolic_name</VT>
      #       </COMPU-CONST>
      #    </COMPU-SCALE>
      # </COMPU-METHOD>
      edl_ev = {}
      for node in xml_tree.findall('.//COMPU-METHOD'):
          if node.find('./SHORT-NAME').text() == 'DT_EDL_EventType':
              for subnode in node.findall('.//COMPU-SCALE'):
                  lower_limit = subnode.find('./LOWER-LIMIT').text()
                  edl_ev_name = subnode.find('./COMPU-CONST/VT').text()
                  if edl_ev_name.startswith('EDL_EV_'):
                      edl_ev[edl_ev_name] = lower_limit or '0' 
      return edl_ev
```

To sum it up: I don't like it. Its clearly a XML-parsing beginners code and ugly/tedious to maintain/unflexible/DRY-violating/etc... Is there a better (declarative?) way to read in XML?

Comment: This is not gonna be a complete answer, but `find`, `findall`, etc can use more XPath features than you are currently taking advantage of: see http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax for a list.

Comment: If you're just traversing the XML tree to collect data, wouldn't it be more efficient for you to use the [SAX](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) approach instead of the DOM one?

Comment: ... I misunderstood your XML structure; that probably won't help as much as I thought it would.

Comment: @Zack You misunderstood, which exactly supports my critique on my code... if it weren't my own code, I'd slate it as complete crap ;)

Comment: @Vroomfondel Actually I meant that as a critique of your *XML*; I am not an expert in this area, but I'm really not sure it's possible to do "find all COMPU-METHOD nodes that have a direct child that is a SHORT-NAME node whose contents are the string 'DT_EDL_EventType' and then extract stuff from the COMPU-SCALE direct child of those COMPU-METHOD nodes" any more elegantly than you have.  But if SHORT-NAME were an *attribute*, then it would be possible.

Comment: @Zack Thanks, but I have to pass on your compliment to the true creators of this piece of ...errhm...XML... the AUTOSAR group. I am just trying to write a code generator which uses the config data from there. I will appreciate any pointer on how to structure XML data the right way for the most common uses (database in this case), so if you can provide links...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the llml library's examples. ([look here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)) Specifically I think you'll want to take a look at the [XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) function

Comment: Try to avoid answers that are heavily dependent on links.  If those links rot, this answer will not be useful.  Perhaps you can imitate some of that content here?